# Map error with function

Tags: java

this is what i have so far and what im trying to do i dont know how to access both parts of the split this code is really wrong but i dont know how to do what i want(yes it is for school)

```
public class Relatives
    {
        private Map<String,Set<String>> map;

        /**
         * Constructs a relatives object with an empty map
         */
        public Relatives()
        {
            map = new TreeMap<String,Set<String>>();
        }

        /**
         * adds a relationship to the map by either adding a relative to the
         * set of an existing key, or creating a new key within the map
         * @param line a string containing the key person and their relative
         */
            public void setPersonRelative(String line)
{
    String[] personRelative = line.split(" ");

    if(map.containsKey(personRelative[0]))
    {
        map.put(personRelative[0],map.get(personRelative[1])+personRelative[1]);
    }
    else
    {
        map.put(personRelative[0],personRelative[1]);
    }
}
```

im trying to access the person and add to there current relatives and if the dont exist create a new person with that relative

how would i format it so it returns like this

```
Dot is related to Chuck Fred Jason Tom
Elton is related to Linh
```

i have this but get error

```
public String getRelatives(String person)
{
    return map.keySet();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add an item to a Set using the `+=` operator; you must use the `add` method.

Also, you have to create the set the first time you are going to use it.

The fixed code could look like:

```
        String[] personRelative = line.split(" ");
        String person = personRelative[0];
        String relative = personRelative[1];
        if(map.containsKey(person))
        {
            map.get(person).add(relative);
        }
        else
        {
            Set<String> relatives = new HashSet<String>();
            relatives.add(relative);
            map.put(person,relatives);
        }
```